# How to show the path of the script of the Azure runbook in Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-bicep

I am want to deploy an Azure Automation Account runbook with Bicep with below code:

```
resource automationAccount 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts@2019-06-01' = {
  name: 'name'
}

resource automationRunbook 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks@2019-06-01' = {
  parent: automationAccount
  name: 'name'
  location: 'westeurope'
  properties: {
    logVerbose: true
    logProgress: true
    runbookType: 'Script'
    publishContentLink: {
      uri: 'uri'
      version: '1.0.0.0'
    }
    description: 'description'
  }
}
```

I want to use a runbook which is on my Azure Repos. Can I use a relative path such as `../scripts/runbook.ps1`  as I do in Powershell? I see that there isn't any property for that but I am asking if I miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/2019-06-01/automationaccounts/runbooks?tabs=bicep#contentlink), you may leverage 'uri' property.

To use a relative path, you may leverage [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameters) section and [variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/variables) section. Something like:

```
param runbooksUri string = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/'

var testScripts = {
  testrunbooks: [
    {
      name: 'XXXXXXX'
      url: uri(runbooksUri, 'xxxxxxx.ps1')
    }
    {
      name: 'YYYYYYY'
      url: uri(runbooksUri, 'yyyyyyy.ps1')
    }
  ]
}

resource automationRunbook 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks@2019-06-01' = [for i in range(0, length(testScripts.testrunbooks)): {
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  properties: {
    publishContentLink: {
      uri: testScripts.testrunbooks[i].url
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    }
  }
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
}]
```

Comment: The thing is that my runbook is not exposed to web, is there a way to do directly from Azure Repos? It doesn't answer my question like this.